How can I pass my session data (auth.js) to my pages.js and server components in my next.js app?
I'm using nextJs and Auth.js in my app. I used my header component to call  await auth() to get the current session data of the user upon first signin in. My question is how can I passed that session data from my header component to my pages (page.js) and server components without using URL Query Parameters? I want to use the id data inside the session object to fetch data from my database.
For additional context, I have a fetch function in my page.js, and these functions need the id data that's in session. I don't want to put await auth() in every page.js cause it might incur additional cost in my app.
here is some code snippet from my header component located in app/components/Header.js
import { auth } from "../_lib/auth";

async function Header() {
    const session = await auth();
    const { id, name, storeLogo } = 
         session?.user?.completeUserData;
    
    ... more code }

This session will return data about the current session and I want to pass this session to my page.js files located in app/orders/page.js and app/store/page.js.
How can we do this? and without making the page.js into a client component.
Thank you for your answers.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hi melvio, just added some code snippets. hope it can help

You can directly get your session data in a server component (page.js | page.tsx)
import { auth } from "../_lib/auth"

export default async function Page() {
    const session = await auth()
    const id = session?.user?.id || ""
}

